# Definition of Gamma function.

Tags: gamma-function, gaussian-integral

Hi I have a question about gamma function integral, we know:
 $$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$(for $z>0$)
now I want solving this integral by using $\Gamma$ function:
$$\int_0^\infty l^{n-1}e^{\alpha l^2}dl$$
Please help me for solving that.

Comment: Use $x=-\alpha l^2$.

Comment: Please make the question more presentable and fit for this site.Note that this is not a site of problem solving.

Comment: @Hossein M Nothing is clearly visible what you have written in comments,use mathjax properly.

Comment: that means the answer is : $\frac{1}{2(-\alpha)^{\frac{m}{2}}} \Gamma (\frac{m}{2})$